# Can VS2008 Testrunner run MbUnit tests or not?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, tfs, mbunit

Ok, so I keep seeing how VS2008 has this nice unit test display and I can see people running NUnit tests within it on Dimecasts.net and [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/astopford/archive/2008/07/03/mbunit-v3-in-visual-studio-team-system-2008.aspx) seems to imply that MbUnit v3 should have support for using visual studio's test runner.  And yet I can't get it to recognize my tests.

Has anyone else been able to get Visual Studio to run their MbUnit tests and if so did you have to do anything special to get it configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to install Gallio 3.0.5 or better from http://www.gallio.org.  It automatically installed in Visual Studio Professional or Team Editions.  Note: VS Standard doesn't support test projects.  After installing Gallio, you can create MbUnit test projects that should work right.  I was able to run Xunit.NET tests with this setup (in VS 2008 Professional).

Comment: Ah didn't realize that you had to create a specific project type.

Answer (score 2):

It is supported but you must modify your project file slightly by adding the right ProjectTypeGuid so that VSTS recognizes it as a test project:

http://alexduggleby.com/2008/02/19/turning-a-class-library-project-into-a-mstest-project-or-using-mbunit-mstest-and-other-frameworks-in-one-project/

Be aware that we are still ironing out some performance issues with large test projects in VSTS.

Comment: Still not seeing any of my tests.  I'm using MbUnit 3.0.5.546

Answer (score 1):

Try using MbUnit v3 alpha 3 (if you aren't already), and see if this article helps:

http://weblogs.asp.net/astopford/archive/2008/07/03/mbunit-v3-in-visual-studio-team-system-2008.aspx